# Can a class be Sendable if it holds a reference to a non-Sendable singleton?

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

Suppose I have a class whose only state is a reference to a singleton class:

```swift
class MyClass {
    let networkHelper: NetworkHelper

    func makeNetworkRequest(_ url: URL) {
        networkHelper.actuallyMakeNetworkRequest(url)
    }
}
```

The `NetworkHelper` class is not `Sendable`; it maintains some mutable state (although that state is mostly invisible to outside callers). However, the class *is* a singleton and so any two instances of `MyClass` will always hold references to the same `NetworkHelper`.

Given that `MyClass` contains no mutable state of its own, and that it does hold a reference to a non-`Sendable` class instance, does `MyClass` conform to `Sendable`?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sendable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, because `NetworkHelper` is not `Sendable`, `MyClass` cannot be `Sendable` either. The fact that `NetworkHelper` is a singleton is immaterial.

FWIW, the compiler will help you out here: If you attempt to make `MyClass` conform to `Sendable` (by making it `final` and adding `Sendable` conformance), the compiler will tell you about the issue with `NetworkHelper` not being `Sendable`:

```swift
final class MyClass: Sendable {
    let networkHelper: NetworkHelper = .shared    // Stored property 'networkHelper' of 'Sendable'-conforming class 'MyClass' has non-sendable type 'NetworkHelper'

    func makeNetworkRequest(_ url: URL) {
        networkHelper.actuallyMakeNetworkRequest(url)
    }
}
```

[image]

For `MyClass` to be `Sendable`, you will need to make `NetworkHelper` conform to `Sendable`, too.

FWIW, if `NetworkHelper` has a mutable state, you probably want to make it threadsafe, anyway, and once you do that, making it `Sendable`, too, is easy.

Answer (score 0):

From documentaion

> Sendable Classes To satisfy the requirements of the Sendable protocol,
> a class must:
>
> Be marked final
>
> Contain only stored properties that are immutable and sendable
>
> Have no superclass or have NSObject as the superclass
>
> Classes marked with @MainActor are implicitly sendable, because the
> main actor coordinates all access to its state. These classes can have
> stored properties that are mutable and nonsendable.
>
> Classes that don’t meet the requirements above can be marked as
> @unchecked Sendable, disabling compile-time correctness checks, after
> you manually verify that they satisfy the Sendable protocol’s semantic
> requirements.

According to this, to be sendable

- Your MyClass should be final
- Your singleton, networkHelper should be immutable and sendable
- Should have no superclasses [Which already is]